# Intellij Play 2.4.6 Reverse Routing

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

If I import my existing Play 2.4.6 project to IntelliJ IDEA 15, I get the following error on redirect.

How I can resolve it? I installed the Scala plugin.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Scala Plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, at default play import play.api.data.From class in twirl template, instead of play.data.From. I add the following in head of my template.

```
@import play.data.Form
@(form: Form[forms.OpeningTimeCreateForm])
```

Now I see now error.